# compare lines between s3 bucket and csv file and send to s3

Tags: bash, csv, amazon-s3, compare

I have s3 bucket with zip files. the path to the zip files is s3://bucketName/tech/type/serialNumber.

I also have csv file that contains region, serialNumber and type

I need to compare the serialNumber and type from s3 bucket with serialNumber and type from csv and upload the folder with the zip files to location in another s3 bucket under the region that aligned to this serial and type from csv.

I have no idea how even start :)
i hope i explain my self good enough

**im writing the script in bash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to load the source data into a **database**.

Then, your application can read the CSV file and query the database for appropriate information. (This is why databases exist!)

Another approach would be to have your application read through the CSV file. For each entry, it would **download the matching file from S3** and process it as necessary.

Or, you could just **download *all* the data from S3** and do everything locally (which could mean on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance).

I suggest you **pick a programming language** (eg Python) rather than attempting to do this in bash.